# How to obtain previous (not the current) passwords from keychain on iOS?

Tags: ios, keychain

I’m helping a person that does everything just in iOS. What happened is the person did a Password change in safari.  It was one of the usual dialogues - enter current password and input new password twice. He used the keychain to fill out the first field and the generate safe password feature to fill the other.  And after submission there was the popovers to update the password which he confirmed.
Now, apparently on the form there was a checkbox or so that was required for the change so the website hasn’t updated the password.  He can no longer log in as the old password  is already updated  on all his devices.

On a desktop machine i would have just restored the keychain. I thought there was a similar option for the iCloud backup - apparently not.

How can one recover from such a situation?

Answer (score 5):

The older passwords are unfortunately not stored in the keychain and cannot be recovered from the iCloud backup.

Your only option is to use the account recovery methods made available by that specific web site. For example many web sites allow account recovery through sending a password reset link via email.

Comment: That's what I fear. Suppose it makes it more "user friendly".

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of the last part of your comment. iCloud Backup does not backup your keychain. There's multiple things it doesn't backup - Apple specifies on their web sites what is backed up by it. The iCloud Keychain Sync feature synchronizes the current contents of the Keychain - old passwords are not stored. I think some users might consider it a security problem if they could not remove a password from Keychain.

Comment: I get your points. It is just the frustration of how poorly designed the password update  feature turns out to be.  I mean it  blocks the view so one can’t know whether the change was successful and then things are permanently lost.

Comment: Only way is not to press save unless you have confirmed that your password is really changed.

Comment: Yes, but then you need to note the newly generated password, as this will be lost once the dialog is clicked out of sight. I know doable, but easy to overlook.

Comment: My exp: safari suggested strong password. Then after I logged in and logged out I forgot that I changed password and used old pass to login back again - it suggested to save it and it basically overwrote the new strong password it stored in keychain, locking myself in position where I cannot recover my account.

Comment: Sounds like a poorly designed site - which web site are we talking about?

Comment: Lesson learned: Don't trust Apple with anything. They cannot be bothered to make a backup or provide a history for my most important data. I just have been permanently locked out from a very important site, because Keychain updated my password without even prompting me about it. That bug would be annoying enough on its own, but that they don't keep previous passwords after screwing up like this is completely unacceptable.

Comment: Keychain does not update the password without prompting. Use the site’s account recovery mechanism to regain access.